# How to compile LuaJit MSVC with DLUAJIT_ENABLE_LUA52COMPAT x86?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, luajit

I am able to successfully build/compile LuaJit in static mode by doing msvcbuild.bat static. Though at the bottom of [LuaJit Extensions](https://luajit.org/extensions.html) it says if I use DLUAJIT_ENABLE_LUA52COMPAT option while building I will be able to use Lua5.2 components. Yet I don't see anywhere in the msvcbuild.bat file where I could add this on. If anyone has any information it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line you want to change starts with LJCOMPILE=cl right near the top of [msvcbuild.bat](https://github.com/LuaJIT/LuaJIT/blob/b2307c8ad817e350d65cc909a579ca2f77439682/src/msvcbuild.bat#L18)
just add /DLUAJIT_ENABLE_LUA52COMPAT to end of it.

Answer (score 0):

The `DLUAJIT_ENABLE_LUA52COMPAT` option is in the `src/Makefile`.
If you want to build Luajit use `DLUAJIT_ENABLE_LUA52COMPAT` option, you should modify the `Makefile` and rebuild by `make`.